# Error in 1:N : NA/NaN argument

Tags: r

I'm using this data:https://www.dropbox.com/s/m02z4ykirfc1838/data.txt?dl=0

I'm trying to run the following model:

```
inputs<- data.frame(data[,c(1,2,3,4,5)]) # seleciona coluna 2 do objeto data
outputs <- data.frame(data[,c(6,7)]) # seleciona colunas 3, 4 e 5 do objeto data
N<- dim(data)[19] # número de DMUs
s <- dim(inputs)[5] # número de inputs
m <- dim(outputs)[2] # número de outputs
f.rhs <- c(rep(0,1,N),1) # RHS
f.dir <- c(rep("<=",1,N),"=") # direção das restrições
aux <- cbind(-1*inputs,outputs) # matriz com os coeficientes tecnológicos em (6)
for (i in 1:N) {
f.obj <- c(0*rep(1,s),as.numeric(outputs[i,])) # coeficientes da função objetivo
f.con <- rbind(aux ,c(as.numeric(inputs[i,]), + rep(0,1,m))) # adiciona a restrição b
T
z=1
results <- lp("max",as.numeric(f.obj),f.con,f.dir,f.rhs,scale=1,compute.sens=TRUE) # resolve PPL
multipliers <- results$solution # multiplicadores
efficiency <- results$objval # indices de eficiência
duals <- results$duals # 
if (i==1) {
 weights <- multipliers
 effcrs <- efficiency
 lambdas <- duals [seq(1,N)]
} else {
 weights <- rbind(weights,multipliers)
 effcrs <- rbind(effcrs , efficiency)
 lambdas <- rbind(lambdas,duals[seq(1,N)])
}
}
```

However, I get this error stuff:

Error in 1:N : NA/NaN argument

I really need a hand on it.

Comment: What is function lp. It is never defined. Are you loading some libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know the lp function but I saw that the way you defined N , s , m were wrong. You had the value in the [] rathere than dim(data)[1] or dim(data)[2]. Now the error in the loop is gone. When you defined
     N <- dim(data)[19]
N got defined as NA so the loop was created for 1:NA which is NAN

Try this

---

```
data <- read.table("~/Documents/data.txt",header=F)
inputs<- data.frame(data[,c(1,2,3,4,5)]) # seleciona coluna 2 do objeto data
outputs <- data.frame(data[,c(6,7)]) # seleciona colunas 3, 4 e 5 do objeto data
N<- dim(data)[1] # número de DMUs
s <- dim(inputs)[2] # número de inputs
m <- dim(outputs)[2] # número de outputs
f.rhs <- c(rep(0,1,N),1) # RHS
f.dir <- c(rep("<=",1,N),"=") # direção das restrições
aux <- cbind(-1*inputs,outputs) # matriz com os coeficientes tecnológicos em (6)
for (i in 1:N) {
  f.obj <- c(0*rep(1,s),as.numeric(outputs[i,])) # coeficientes da função objetivo
  f.con <- rbind(aux ,c(as.numeric(inputs[i,]), + rep(0,1,m))) # adiciona a restrição b
  T
  z=1
  results <- lp("max",as.numeric(f.obj),f.con,f.dir,f.rhs,scale=1,compute.sens=TRUE) # resolve PPL
  multipliers <- results$solution # multiplicadores
  efficiency <- results$objval # indices de eficiência
  duals <- results$duals # 
  if (i==1) {
    weights <- multipliers
    effcrs <- efficiency
    lambdas <- duals [seq(1,N)]
  } else {
    weights <- rbind(weights,multipliers)
    effcrs <- rbind(effcrs , efficiency)
    lambdas <- rbind(lambdas,duals[seq(1,N)])
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it, but, how I've got less that 15 in reputation, it won't show up there =(

Comment: oh ok :) Thanx this might help you